# Build rpm on CentOS for RHEL

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rhel7

I need to install some software which is not available pre-compiled on a client's RHEL Server. I decided to create a rpm for easier installation on multiple systems. 
As i have no RHEL subscription, can i create the rpm locally on CentOS and then install it on the RHEL Systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that will work perfectly for "noarch" rpms; but for any other rpm; I would strongly recommend building rpms on the same machine as the one where you will install it. Consider downloading the source rpms and rebuilding the rpms yourself (using `rpmbuild --rebuild`)